# At the peak of their power, out of Dooku and Luke who was the better lightsaber combatant?

Tags: star-wars

Based on existing information, who would be considered the better lightsaber combatant? Dooku is an expert fencer and Luke is killed with the Force.

My main reason for asking was the cover of a new book [A Brief Guide to Star Wars: The Unauthorized Guide to George Lucas's Epic](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/13587199-a-brief-guide-to-star-wars) in which you see what appears to be both characters.

[image]

Comment: This is a [Gorilla vs. Shark question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/).

Comment: Does't matter. Lucas would win anyway. First he gets to sell $10Mil of merchandise of the fight, then he changes the outcome 10 years later.

Comment: @DVK - I wish I could upvote this 1000 times

Comment: Dooku would microwave Luke like a Jedi-potpie because Obi-Wan would, as usual, neglect to say "Oh, BTW, look out for the Force Lightning."

Comment: Luke defeated a force entity several times.  I don't think dooku could have once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't know who'd win in a duel, especially since Luke's skill and power changed significantly over his lifetime. On a dumb level, Anakin defeated Dooku as a teen, and Luke defeated Vader as a teen, but Vader wasn't really as powerful a fighter as Anakin, what with being "more machine than a man, twisted and evil". So lightsaber skill is not a good basis for comparison.

**But as far as raw Force power, we know that Luke had as big a Midichloran count as Anakin, and both were pretty much the highest count among Jedi (Celestials like Son and Daughter nonwithstanding)**

Comment: Fair enough. I only asked because of the cover of a new book A Brief Guide to Star Wars: The Unauthorized Guide to George Lucas's Epic sparked my imagination.

Comment: We don't know Luke's midi-chlorian count

Comment: @Valorum - I distinctly remember reading *somewhere* in (presumably EU) canon that it was suppposed to be as high as Anakin. No clue anymore where that was.

Comment: @DVK-on-Ahch-To - Supposedly, he's as powerful as Anakin; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/143512/how-many-midichlorians-does-luke-skywalker-have. There's no mention of midi-chlorian count though. Note that Yoda is a more powerful Jedi than Anakin despite having a lower count.

Comment: @Valorum - Debatable. When 900 years Anakin is, he may possess same experience as Yoda and be able to win.

Comment: @DVK-on-Ahch-To - When he's 900, he won't look as good as Yoda. The implication is that he'll be loooooong dead.